# Assign JQuery variables to Html.Actionlink to pass parameters to new view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, razor, actionlink

I want to pass JQuery variables to a different action in the application. I don't want to use AJAX as the action does a lot of processing and opens a report in a different view.

JQuery:

```
 var from = $('#dateFrom').val();
 var to = $('#dateTo').val();
 var uid = $('#projectUid').text();
 console.log('From: ' + from + '   To: ' + to + '  uid: ' + uid);                  

 $('#dateFrom').change(function () {
     from =  $('#dateFrom').val();
 });

 $('#dateTo').change(function () {
     to = $('#dateTo').val();
 });
```

I know that Razor is processed server side, so I want to post to the action that will create the new view, kind of like:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#btnSubmit.click').click(function () {
          @Html.ActionLink("View Report", "PdfReport", "ReportGenerator"), { from: from }, { to: to }, { projectreference: uid };
      });
 });

 <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Create Report" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" />
```

Then pick up the parameters from the post:

```
  public IActionResult PdfReport(string from, string projectreference, string to)
  {
      var dateFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(from).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
      var dateTo = Convert.ToDateTime(to).AddMinutes(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");  
      var puid = projectreference;    
  }
```

So my question is, how can I pass JQuery variables to an action as parameters in HtmlActionLink. I am assuming you cant as Razor is compiled server side. With that in mind, what is the alternative without using AJAX.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't want to use ajax?

Comment: I am bailing out of the view, so I don't need a callback.

Comment: I don't know enough about actionlink to answer your question, but you could condense your code a bit by adding the first 3 `var` statements to trigger after `$('#btnSubmit.click')`.  By doing it this way, you wouldn't need to worry about the state of the inputs until you are ready to use them, and can cut out the `.change` part

Comment: You should simply add those fields inside a `<form>` element and submit that form properly. That way, you will have it a lot easier to open the report. And you don't actually need JavaScript for that.

Comment: I have done that, I was keen to know if it's possible.